# intent.putExtra not working

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I need to pass information between two activities, but for some reason the information isn't sent / recieved.

LogCat doesn't give me any errors. The dubugger clearly shows *something* is added to the intent (variabl: mExtras), but it's hard to interpret exactly what is added. After that it gives me "source not found" and doesn't help me further.

But first things first. Am I doing things right so far?

Sending:

```
Intent intent = new Intent ( this, TaskListActivity.class );
intent.putExtra ( ProjectManager.ID, mId.toString () );
startActivity ( intent );
```

Recieving:

```
Intent intent = getIntent ();
mId = UUID.fromString ( intent.getStringExtra ( ProjectManager.ID ) );
```

Comment: Did you try those answers? Is it working?

Comment: No success yet. Still working on it. :/

Comment: Did you ever find the issue?

Answer (score 1):

add following code after intent:

```
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
String exampleString = extras.getString(ProjectManager.ID);
```

Answer (score 1):

what is `ProjectManager.ID`?, you should pass same unique`key` while recieving data from putExtra even way of receiving data is wrong, check below code:

*Sending:*

```
Intent intent = new Intent ( this, TaskListActivity.class );
intent.putExtra (ProjectManager.ID, mId.toString () );
startActivity ( intent );
```

Recieving:

```
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    if(extras!=null){
  String _Str = extras.getString(ProjectManager.ID);
}
```

Comment: It's a constant (String) defined in another class.

Comment: ProjectManager.ID contain similar data in both activity?

Comment: Yup. Well ID refers to the same string. :)

Comment: then check/print log `mId.toString ()` before sending to another activity, its really contain value? .

Comment: The bundle is seriously confusing, but yes, I can find both the key the and value in the debugger before they're sent - a large number of times for some reason. So, it would appear they're not recieved.

Answer (score 0):

**Try This to Receive Extra:**

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
String id;

if (extras != null) {
    id= extras.getString(key);

}
```

Comment: I dunno where you are struggling exactly. Refer This Article http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidIntent/article.html

Comment: Me neither. Seems simple enough, but it just doesn't work. Strange.

Answer (score 0):

In FirstActivity.java write these code.

```
 Intent i = new Intent(FirstActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
 i.putExtra("KEY",value);
 startActivity(i);
```

In SecondActivity.java:

```
Bundle extras=getIntent().getExtras();
String name=extras.getString("key"); //if data you are sending is String.
int i=extras.getInt("key"); //if data you are sending is integer.
```

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve the extras in the new activity:

```
String valueOfExtra;
Intent i = getIntent();
//check first
if(i.hasExtra("extra1")){
  valueOfExtra = i.getStringExtra("extra1");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the above worked for me when trying to retrieve EXTRA_TEXT.  I was incorrectly trying to retrieve it via:

```
String data = extras.getString("EXTRA_TEXT");
```

To I had to remove the quotes and prefix EXTRA_TEXT with 'Intent.'

caller:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, AboutActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "hello from menu item selected"); 
startActivity(intent);
```

receiver:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    String data = extras.getString(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
    TextView tv = findViewById(R.id.myAboutText);
    tv.setText(data);
}
```